# Failed to Compile Next.js 13 and TailwindCSS

Tags: node.js, typescript, tailwind-css, prisma, next.js13

Failed to compile
app\layout.tsx
An error occured in `next/font`.

```
Error: Malformed PostCSS Configuration
    at C:\Users\Farah Zahira\next-app\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\blocks\css\plugins.js:156:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at getPostCssPlugins (C:\Users\Farah Zahira\next-app\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\blocks\css\plugins.js:130:13)
    at async C:\Users\Farah Zahira\next-app\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\blocks\css\index.js:124:36
    at async C:\Users\Farah Zahira\next-app\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\postcss-loader\src\index.js:51:41
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Farah Zahira\next-app\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:105:20)
This error occurred during the build process and can only be dismissed by fixing the error.
```

Im trying to create a next.js project with tailwind and typescript, however upon running npm run dev, I get this error and I have tried to check my postcss.config.js file and nothing seems to be a problem, aside from that the packages are all installed in the node modules folder so I am at a loss

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.